# C# model - add single and List of elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using .NET Core.

I have a class which has a string party and a List Accounts and a List Amounts. I want to be able to populate this class - I am unsure how.

The class is:

```
public class pivotTest
{
    public string Party { get; set; }
    IList<string> Accounts { get; set; }
    IList<double?> Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Now with this class, there's one party with many accounts and amounts, an example would be:

```
Jerry
Bank1 1000
Bank2 500
Bank 200

Thomas
Bank1 3000
Bank2  500
```

And ideally, I would like it to displayed like this.

How would I go about populating this class?

Comment: I think it would be better if you created another class that contains the account name and amount and then have a list of that so you can keep that data together.  Alternatively you could use value tuples like `List<(string Name, double? Amount)> Accounts`

Comment: What you mean with population ? To a Listbox ? To A File, or a stream ? Your example output does not show, what Accounts and Amount is. If you have the assumption Accounts and Amount are equal-length lists, than this is a bad design. Use only one list.

Comment: @juharr Okay hhmm, how would I go about doing this? Can you give an example show a good link to this? It does make sense

Comment: Here's a blog by Jon Skeet about this specific anti-pattern. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Comment: Where did you want to populate?The model or the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use separate lists for **Accounts** and **Amount**. A `Dictionary` is a much better choice for something like this. Also, in order to "populate," you will need a class **constructor**.

```
public class PivotTest
{
    public string Party { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double?> Accounts { get; set; }

    public PivotTest()
    {
        Accounts = new Dictionary<string, double?>();
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Party);

        foreach(string account in Accounts.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{account} {Accounts[account].ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    PivotTest jerry = new PivotTest();
    jerry.Party = "Jerry";
    jerry.Accounts.Add("Bank1", 1000);
    jerry.Accounts.Add("Bank2", 500);
    jerry.Accounts.Add("Bank", 200);
    jerry.Display();
```